# Autolayout: UIButton ends up beyond the screen boundary

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-universal-app

I'm building a universal application with XCode, and I'm following the procedure from the 3rd chapter of "Beginning iPhone Development with Swift".

I have a view with two buttons named "left" and "right", and a label with empty text. That's how they're positioned at the beginning:

[image]

Next I add some constraints. The steps are:

1. I ctrl-drag from the label to the view, and add two constraints: "center horizontally in container" and "top space to top layout guide". Then I select the label and click on "update constraints".
2. For both the left and right buttons, I add a constraint: "vertical center in container".
3. I add a "pin" constraint to separate the left button of 32 points from the left, and the same goes for the right button (but I add a separation from the right).

To explain this last step, that's what I add for the left button:

[image]

And that's what I add for the right button:

[image]

Next, since there are some warning, I select both the right and left buttons, and click on "update frames". This is what I end up with:

[image]

The right button is 32 points beyond the right boundary of the screen, and when I run the application the button (obviously) appears cut out. The pin constraint of the right button got automatically updated to -32 instead of 32, and if I change it again I get an error, saying that two constraints are conflicting:

[image]

Comment: Did you delete the constraints and re-add? It looks like the first and second items are the wrong way round

Comment: Uncheck the Constraints to margins option, it can make some funny stuff if enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question you need to set constraint left and right from textfiled as per image I’ve set below.

Set left constraint to textfield and left button.

[image]

Set right constraint to textfield and right button.

[image]

I've given top constraint to textfield,leading and trailing to textfield.

[image]

[image]

**RESULT : **

[image]

Hope this solves your issue.